# How to re align the components in Grid layout in swt in java?

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

I have a page. in that three composites are there one by one.simply i am putting the composites into grid layout .

```
composite1
Composite2
Composite3
```

Based on some condition, i will set visible false composite 1. So remaining components will be visible true. My problem here, when i set visible false composite 1, i want to move Composite 2, composite 3 go to UP.

```
Composite2
Composite3
```

But i am facing problem here

```
Space
Composite2
Composite3
```

in the place of **Composite1** , i am getting **space** due to setVisible (false). But i want to remove space and **Composite2** has to be place in **Composite1** instead of space, **Composite3** to be place in **Composite2**. i tried to **setComputeSize(0,0)** for the the **Composite1**. But Its not working.Could anyone please help me.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. If you think that it isn't a duplicate, please clarify, how your question differs from the one I posted.

Comment: Hi its not duplicate.Its realted to realignment of the widgets.Could you please share me the link what you have posted

Comment: So how does your question from the [potential duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189543/swt-components-relayout-after-visibility-set-to-false)?

Comment: Sorry it duplicated .. really its very useful..thanks .Just now i looked the code...really thanks a lot..